# How to include icon in module install page in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

[image]

I am creating a Custom module in Drupal 8 I want to show (like above pic) help, permission and configure I don't know to do this. help me to solve

Answer (score 0):

For adding help icon, you have to call the hook_help() in you module.

For adding permission icons, you have to create custom permissions (mymodule.permissions.yml) into your module.

Once you added those code, it automatically will creates the icon under your module.

To add configure icon with link, you have create the config route in your module and add that route name into mymodule.info.yml file as below.
configure: